# What would be the negation of, "If the new action figure is released, I will buy two" without the use of words like no, not, etc.?

Tags: logic

I know the negative of a conditional statement of "if P, then Q" is "P and not Q" but is there a way of writing it to avoid the use of words like not, none, no, etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\;{\small\bullet}\;\;$"The new action figure has been released, but I won't buy two of them."

Explanation:

The original statement has the form "If $P$, then $Q$", where

$\qquad P =\;$"The new action figure is released."

$\qquad Q =\;$"I'll buy two."

So to negate it, you need to assert that $P$ is true, but $Q$ is false.

Using a real-world interpretation of "$Q$ is false", it could be phrased as

$\;{\small\bullet}\;\;$"The new action figure has been released, but I'll buy at most one of them."

The reason I call this a "real-world" interpretation, is that, if taken literally, the negation of "I won't buy two" allows for the possibility of buying more than two. But from a common sense perspective, that's silly. If I say "I won't buy two", that strongly suggests that buying more than two is also barred.